# Поиск максимальных элементов в списке

Tags: c++, stl

Есть некий класс

```
class A
{
   // Какой-то в меру сложный класс
}
```

В классе А есть несколько небольших контейнеров элементарных типов (небольшие - 4 - 15 элементов).
Для А заданы операторы сравнения

```
bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs);
// другие операторы (>, < и т.д.)
```

Есть список (вектор) объектов А

```
typedef std::vector<A> ListA;
```

Важно! - максимальное количество элементов в списке - 10 (т.е. невелико)

Требуется найти позиции всех максимальных элементов списка. Я решил задачу следующим образом:

```
std::vector<size_t> findHighestElements(const ListA &list) {
    std::vector<size_t> v;
    v.reserve(list.size());
    v.push_back(0);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        if        (list[i]  > list[v[0]]) {
            v.clear();
            v.push_back(i);
        } else if (list[i] == list[v[0]]) {
            v.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

В принципе, задачу можно решить используя алгоритмы STL:
1) Используя `std::max_element`
2) Предварительно отсортировав список `std::sort`
3) Используя изначально упорядоченный контейнер (но придется сохранять изначальные позиции элементов)

Проблема в том, что несмотря на небольшой размер списка, эту операцию (поиск максимальных элементов) нужно выполнять много раз (миллионы вариантов списка).
Вопрос, собственно, что будет быстрее?

P.S. В документации написано, что `std::vector<A>::clear()` имеет линейную по кол-ву элементов сложность. Если A имеет сложный деструктор, это понятно, нужно вызвать деструкторы для всех элементов. А если `A` - элементарный тип? Будет ли сложность константной (известно, что `clear()` не изменяет `capacity`)? Собственно, в моем алгоритме меня смущает только этот момент (N вызовов `clear()` в худшем случае).

Comment: я бы наверное сделал в 2 прохода по массиву. 1 - найти максимальный. 2 - найти позиции. Но думаю лучше написать все варианты, благо пишутся быстро и сравнить.

Comment: `boost::multi_index` возможно может подойти

Answer (score 1):

Я сначала думал что быстрее одним циклом(ну или готовым алгоритмом) найти максимальный элемент, а потом другим циклом позиции. Но мне кажется ваш алгоритм самый лучший вариант. Он работает за один проход циклом по массиву. Вариант с сортировкой отпадает сразу, сортировка работает куда дольше чем один проход циклом, да еще придется кроме элементов хранить позиции... 3 вариант тоже думаю не очень.

Comment: а вы замерьте :) он не сильно лучше https://ideone.com/gcH7o3 разница в пределах погрешности.